# Network names in Windows

Tags: networking

On windows PCs, when you visit the Network Connections View (`ncpa.cpl` or via Control Panel), most connected network adapters show a network "name".

In the attached screenshot, this would happen to be "FRITZ!Box 6591 Cable OE 3".

showing network adapter with erroneusly detected network name
[image]

In other locations I visit, when connected to other networks, this might e.g. say "eduroam".

The strange thing is, in my home network, there is currently no FritzBox 6591 available (but I know for a fact that there has been one at some point in the past). Right now, there is only a FritzBox 7490 in the same network, and it only serves as an IP client. The Routing and DHCP are done by a Unifi DreamMachine Pro.

I aspire to define a name for the network myself, such that the network name is provided by my network infrastructure gear.

- How is this feature called, and what is necessary to provide it?
- Can it be done specifically with a Unifi controller?

I am aware of ways to manually set the network name individually on every windows client, as e.g. detailed here: [(in the lower half of the article)](https://www.itechtics.com/change-network-adapter-names/). That works, but is not what I want to do. Instead, I want to have it just like with "eduoam", where the network *somehow* provided the name itself.

On a side-quest, I would like to understand how the current name is kept, even when I am no longer connected to the FritzBox 6591.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. I'm going to try to explain what I can.

What you are referring to is the `ProfileName` of the "Network Profile" Windows gave the connection. The list of profiles can be found in the registry: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles`. The `ProfileName` can be updated there.

Each time you connect to a network, Windows 10 automatically creates a network profile for the connection. It will take on the name of the SSID of the wireless network you connect to, or a generic `Network *` name for wired connections. I think it then identifies when you connect to this network again in the future, by referencing `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures\Unmanaged` where there is a key which links the `ProfileGuid` from the profile list above, to information about the connection such as the `DefaultGatewayMac` address and `DnsSuffix`.

Therefore, what you are seeing in your screenshot is the result of previously connecting to a wireless network that was called `FRITZ!Box 6591 Cable OE 3` which generated a profile with this name. Or, the profile was renamed or created through some other means, such as installed software on your computer. Now when you connect to the network, Windows is recognizing the same or similar information it gathered for this network profile and continues to use that profile and name when it presents it to you in Control Panel.

So, to answer your question, Windows or some other software created this network profile in the past. Windows thinks you are connected to that same network and is re-using the previously assigned name. You can edit this name manually in the registry, but it is NOT obtained from anything on your network, other than when you connect wirelessly, it will use the SSID when creating the profile.

I will note that I was very interested in this question, because I immediately recognized that my current wired connection is named by an older wireless network name. Once I dug in to it, I realized I am still connected to the same network, just now I am using a wired connection and not a wireless connection, and so it is still using the old network profile name.

Comment: Thank you very much, that explains nicely why the old name is kept, how it came into existence and that there is no way to assign it from my infrastructure. The details you gave are very helpful.

That said, I imagine I can manually design some unmanaged signatures and accompanying profiles, such that I can have one *.reg file, which I install on all my pcs (manually, and once), or even per startscript.

Comment: Is it safe to delete profiles at both the above locations? Or is there a standard command that can delete network profiles safely?